# Is there any difference between type? and Nullable<type>?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

In C# are the nullable primitive types (i.e. `bool?`) just aliases for their corresponding `Nullable<T>` type or is there a difference between the two?

Comment: This question should be edited to clarify the name of the primitive type is "bool?" and not "bool". There are good answers below, but the question is unclear.

Comment: I had a similar question regarding `int?` and `Nullable<int>` and found this question (and its answers) to be very helpful.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830/nullableint-vs-int-is-there-any-difference/38679443#38679443

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you look at the IL using [Ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you'll find that they both compile down to `Nullable<bool>`.

Comment: Maybe they don't know what IL or ILDasm mean. Link them?

Comment: While this is true, there are some corner cases of the language, when there **is** a difference between the two. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24738380/1552016) (and the linked question there) for more details.

Answer (score 38):

There is no difference between `bool? b = null` and `Nullable<bool> b = null`. The `?` is just C# compiler syntax sugar.

Answer (score 18):

To access the value of the bool? you need to do the following:

```
bool? myValue = true;
bool hasValue = false;

if (myValue.HasValue && myValue.Value)
{
  hasValue = true;
}
```

Note you can't just do:

```
if (myValue)
{
  hasValue = true;
}
```

Comment: hmm, not sure whether or not to up-vote this as it doesnt answer the question but it's useful and succinct nonetheless! ;-)

Comment: Well, according to Joel you should up-vote if you find it useful - not neccessarily if it's the answer. But then I would say that ;)

Comment: +1, but I would use different names to make it easier to read!

Comment: If prefer to do 'if(myValue == true)' instead.  It works the same way because it will be false if myValue is null.

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised nobody went to the source (the C# spec) yet. From §4.1.10 Nullable types:

> A nullable type is written T?, where T is the underlying type. This syntax is shorthand for System.Nullable<T>, and the two forms can be used interchangeably.

So, no, there isn't any difference between the two forms. (Assuming you don't have any other type called `Nullable<T>` in any of the namespaces you use.)

Answer (score 7):

A `Nullable<T>` is a structure consisting of a T and a bit flag indicating whether or not the T is valid.  A `Nullable<bool>` has three possible values: true, false and null.

**Edit:** Ah, I missed the fact that the question mark after "bool" was actually part of the type name and not an indicator that you were asking a question :).  The answer to your question, then, is "yes, the C# `bool?` is just an alias for `Nullable<bool>`".

Comment: This didn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after seeing your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A `bool` is a value type, therefore it can't contain a NULL value.  If you wrap any value type with `Nullable<>`, it will give it that ability.  Moreover, access methods to the value change by additional properties `HasValue` and `Value`.

But to the question: `Nullable<bool>` and `bool?` are aliases.

Comment: Even though this comment was from way back it's possible that they felt this answer duplicated other answers so they DV'd?

Comment: Apparently I'm not the fastest gun in the west.  All the top answers are within a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no difference.  In summary:

System.Boolean -> valid values : true, false

bool -> alias for System.Boolean

Nullable<bool> -> valid values : true, false, null

bool? -> alias for Nullable<bool>

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Null primitives are just regular primitives wrapped in Nullable.  Any appearances to the contrary are just the compiler and syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 0):

No difference. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

"The syntax T? is shorthand for Nullable, where T is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable."