# LINQ Check exist Username then get that User's ID

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Account table:

```
    table Account
    (
    UserId int identity(1, 1),
    UserName nvarchar(20) not null unique,
    Password nvarchar(20) not null
    )
```

By using LINQ. Whether I can check exist `UserName` for an account then. And it's true then get `UserId` for that account
(I'm use ASP MVC 4 with Entity Framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Linq to query from DB, I prefer to use query expression, that is closer to SQL notation than Lambda notation.

Given that you have the `username`:

```
try {
    int userId = (from x in context.Account
                   where x.UserName == username
                   select x.UserId).SingleOrDefault());

    if (userId > 0){
        // user exists
    }
    else {
        // user does not exist
    }
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex){
    // has more than one element
}
```

Comment: Edit: Much better. :)

Comment: Wait. Actually no it will still return 0. So userId will have a value.

Comment: yes, I've updated this. "OrDefault()" means that will return `default(TSource)` and not `default(TDestiny)` :)

Comment: Yeah. You could maybe project the UserId into a nullable int inside the query, in which case SingleOrDefault() might then return a nullable with no value. Haven't tested this though.

Comment: yes, that's why I've declared userId as `int?` before, but I think that could be better to use same type for `userId` and `x.UserId`

Comment: Dry coding here, but would this work? `int? userId = (from x in context.Account where x.UserName == username select new Nullable<int>(x.UserId)).SingleOrDefault());`

Comment: Won't because this `new int?(x.CodPreco)` is not supported in Linq.

Comment: int? and Nullable<int> are the same thing. Or rather int? is just shorthand for Nullable<int>.

Comment: It works okay, too! It maybe better ideas in some cases for `trycatch` that it return more than one element. I thank you too for the anwser

Comment: @JC. [int? is same thing that Nullable<int>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830)

Comment: What I mean is that `int?` and `Nullable<int>` are the same thing indeed. But Linq does not **support** `int?` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
var user = Context.Accounts.SinlgeOrDefault(user => user.UserName=="yourValue");
if(user!=null)
{
// you can safely access the user properties here
}
```