# When int? and Nullable<int> are the same, why do they behave in a different way?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Consider the below programs. I would like to know why this code behaves in a different way.

This is returning an error during compile time:

```
void access<T>(T val, bool result){
var getaccess = val is int? & result;
}
```

This is not returning any error:

```
void access<T>(T val, bool result){
var getaccess = val is Nullable<int> & result;
}
```

Comment: provide the compile time error (code/description/reference)

Comment: Maybe this will help you [Nullable<int> vs. int? - Is there any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830/nullableint-vs-int-is-there-any-difference). Have a look at the answer from 
qqbenq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nullable<int> vs. int? - Is there any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830/nullableint-vs-int-is-there-any-difference)

Comment: I think it the compiler is expecting the `?` to be part of a ternary expression. If you put parenthesis around it, it works: `(val is int?) & result;`

Comment: I agree, it is a duplicate.. but only because that question is ambiguous and open-ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply because `?` and `&` are overloaded and can also indicate a conditional operator and "address of" respectively. The compiler needs to know what you mean. This fixes it:

```
var getaccess = (val is int?) & result;
```

The compiler message isn't *entirely* clear, but gives us the clues:

```
CS0214  Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe
```

(which is from the `& result`)

```
CS1003  Syntax error, ':' expected
```

(which is from the `?`)

and:

```
CS1525  Invalid expression term ';'
```

(which is also from the `?` because it expects a `: {value if false}` expression before the next semicolon)

Basically, without the parentheses it thinks you mean:

```
var getaccess = (val is int) ? (&result)
```

(with a missing expression for what to do if `val` is *not* an `int`)