# Difference between the two Nullable Types?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between these two

```
public Nullable<bool> val_a { get; set; } 
public bool? val_b { get; set; }
```

These are both Nullable type.

Also how do I test if val_b is nullable in one line ?

Comment: `Also how do I test if val_b is nullable` Do you want to know if it is `null` or `nullable`? They are two very different things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable<int> vs. int? - Is there any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830/nullableint-vs-int-is-there-any-difference)

Answer (score 1):

`bool?` is a short-hand notation for `Nullable<bool>`. They are same.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types):

> Any nullable value type is an instance of the generic System.Nullable structure. You can refer to a nullable value type with an underlying type T in any of the following interchangeable forms: Nullable<T> or T?.

To test if `val_b` is `null`, simply check `val_b.HasValue`. For example:

```
if (val_b.HasValue)
{
   var b = val_b.Value;
}
```

You can also do something like:

```
var b = val_b.GetValueOrDefault();
```

or

```
var b = val_b ?? false;
```

In case of `bool` the `default` would be `false`.

To override the `default` value to `true`, you can use `GetValueOrDefault` overload:

```
var b = val_b.GetValueOrDefault(true);
```

Comment: How do i get the value of val_b safely ?

Comment: @MistyD, check the updated answer

Comment: Hi @mjwills, great suggestion, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the same thing.  Just like using `Int32` or `int`.  No difference.

Testing nullable bools is straight forward but there's a catch.

Common tests like `if (val_a)` and `if (!val_a)` don't work because a nullable bool has three states: `true`, `false` and `null`.

These work because you're doing an explicit comparison:

```
if (val_a == true)
if (val_a == false)
if (val_a == null)
```

You can also use the null coalescing operator if you wish, though this is more useful for other nullable types:

```
if (val_a ?? false)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374663/3980331) if you want to test if a given type is nullable.