# What is the difference between Nullable<bool> and bool?

Tags: c#

When I reverse engineer my classes I get the following:

```
public Nullable<bool> Correct  { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Response { get; set; }
```

I coded:

```
public bool? Correct  { get; set; }
public bool? Response { get; set; }
```

Can someone tell me if there is any difference between these two. I have not seen the `Nullable<bool>` before and I'm not sure why it does not just create a "bool".

Note: I changed my coded to bool? in response to comments by Jon

Comment: I suspect you actually coded `public bool? Correct { get; set; }`. The compiler doesn't convert `bool` into `bool?` automatically.

Comment: You sure you didn't write `bool?` instead of `bool`?

Comment: I noticed that Nullable<bool> requires the System namespace but bool? does not. Anyone know what that is ?

Comment: If you use a different tool to reverse engineer your code, it might produce `bool?` back - this should be a hint to you that there's no difference - the reverse engineering tool cannot know which of the two you wrote.

Comment: `bool?` is just an alias the C# compiler defined for your convenience.

Comment: Now it's really just http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518/is-there-any-difference-between-bool-and-nullablebool?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"A Nullable can be assigned the values true false, or null. The ability to assign null to numeric and Boolean types is especially useful when you are dealing with databases and other data types that contain elements that may not be assigned a value. For example, a Boolean field in a database can store the values true or false, or it may be undefined."

[Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't explain what's going on in the OP's situation - which I suspect to be a misdiagnosis.

Comment: @Jon - Now I realize that the database allows NULLs and my code does not. The database scripts were done by our DBA and I coded the classes (incorrectly). I still wonder why the reverse engineer does not just specify bool?

Comment: Well, at least now you can also do sanity check on your DB.

Comment: I changed my code to use Nullable<bool> and it now asks me to include the System namespace. So are they really the same?

Comment: technically whatever you write they will compile down to Nullable<bool> in IL. so no difference. As far as why require system, it is because it is used as a type. And type needs to be in a namespace

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, they work the same with the difference that you can actually declare/assign it NULL.

Comment: @Alan `Nullable<bool>` and `bool?` is similar to `int` and `System.Int32`. They are just two ways of representing the same thing. You had to add the `System` namespace because you where using the longer version, just like you would need to add `System` if you used `Int32` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone tell me if there is any difference between these two. I
>   have not seen the Nullable before and I'm not sure why it does
>   not just create a "bool"

**technically there is no difference in Nullable and bool?. Whatever you write they will compile down to Nullable in IL**. so no difference.  The ? is just C# compiler syntax.

> why require system for Nullable

it is because it is used as a `type`. And type needs to be in a `namespace`.

**But there is a difference in bool and bool?**. As bool is a simple value type that cannot be assigned null value whereas you can assign value to bool?.

`Nullable` represents a `value type` that can be assigned null and it lies in the namespace `System`.

Further as it can be assigned null therefore you can check whether it has value or not like this

```
if(Correct.HasValue)
{
  //do some work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes **there is difference between `Nullable<bool>` and `bool`**.

```
public Nullable<bool> Correct { get; set; } // can assign both true/false and null
Correct = null;  //possible
```

whereas

in your case you can't have it

```
public bool Correct { get; set; } //can assign only true/false
Correct = null;  //not possible
```

Maybe the previous guy who coded may not exposed to `bool?` dataType.

> **`System.Nullable<bool>` is equivalent to `bool?`**

Update: **There is no difference between `Nullable<bool>` and `bool?`**

Comment: Hello. I just upvoted you because of your answer. Note that I now changed my code to bool? I realize it was my mistake.

Comment: @Alan no difference,known as alias.

Answer (score 2):

`Nullable<bool>` and `bool?` are equivalent ("?" suffix is a *syntactic sugar*).
`Nullable<bool>` means that in addition to typical `bool` values: true and false,
there's a *third* value: *null*.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Null value could be useful if you work with uncertain values, e.g. in some 
cases you can't tell if the instance is correct one or not, if any response
has been given; for instance in your case

```
  // true  - instance is correct
  // false - instance is incorrect
  // null  - additional info required
  public bool? Correct { get; set; }
  // true  - response was given 
  // false - no response
  // null  - say, the response is in the process
  public bool? Response { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

Hint:  `Nullable<Nullable<bool>> n; // not allowed`

[Source msdn Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx)